# magical typo corrector in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, full-text-search

I have some trouble understanding the PostgreSQL documentation. Apparently, the example is text searching for words that are similar(?) to 'caterpiler'. Example is taken from [documentation 41.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/rules-materializedviews.html). Relevant queries are replicated below. The materialized views parts are not central to the question.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER local_file FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE words (word text NOT NULL)
  SERVER local_file
  OPTIONS (filename '/usr/share/dict/words');
```

```sql
-- previously established that foreign table "words"
-- contains zero counts of 'caterpiler'
SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY word <-> 'caterpiler' LIMIT 10;
-- output
/*
 word
---------------
 cater
 caterpillar
 Caterpillar
 caterpillars
 caterpillar's
 Caterpillar's
 caterer
 caterer's
 caters
 catered
(10 rows)
*/
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
 Limit  (cost=11583.61..11583.64 rows=10 width=32) (actual time=1431.591..1431.594 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=11583.61..11804.76 rows=88459 width=32) (actual time=1431.589..1431.591 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: ((word <-> 'caterpiler'::text))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Foreign Scan on words  (cost=0.00..9672.05 rows=88459 width=32) (actual time=0.057..1286.455 rows=479829 loops=1)
               Foreign File: /usr/share/dict/words
               Foreign File Size: 4953699
 Planning time: 0.128 ms
 Execution time: 1431.679 ms
```

I assume that `word <-> 'catepiler'` is using the `tsquery <-> tsquery` syntax but how does that work in this query and how is it producing the output order? Also is the `'caterpiler'::text` in the EXPLAIN ANALYZE just the planner treating all strings as `text` by default, or does that mean some other definition of `<->` is being used?

Furthermore, is a dictionary and/or thesaurus being looked up, or is this a general feature of `<->`? The file path sure looks like a dictionary but it does not appear to be used as such.

Thanks

Comment: text is the most efficient string type and recommend for postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that word <-> 'catepiler' is using the tsquery <-> tsquery syntax

No, it is using [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)'s `text <-> text` operator.  If pg_trgm doesn't exist, then you get an error.

> Also is the 'caterpiler'::text in the EXPLAIN ANALYZE just the planner treating all strings as text by default, or does that mean some other definition of <-> is being used?

The latter, a different definition is being used.

> The file path sure looks like a dictionary but it does not appear to be used as such.

It is list of words, that is not really a dictionary in everyday meaning but nonetheless that is what the file is called.  Note that the example is just using a file which often exists on UNIX-like systems.  Neither the file, nor its choice of name, are part of PostgreSQL.  It is just a handy thing to use in an example.

Comment: thanks so in summary, because strings with unknown types are defaulted to `text`, a module's redefined operator takes precedence, and it does some character comparisons (using trigrams and whatnot)?

Comment: The column "word" is explicitly defined to be of type text, so I don't think defaults necessarily come into play here.  The operator lookup is for `text <-> unknown` and that is compatible with only the `<->` operator from pg_trgm, at which point it knows the literal 'catepillar' also needs to be of text type and labels it as such.

Comment: ahh yes I forgot about that ... got too caught up in the casting to `text`. Thanks again! Spent quite some time not finding this text <-> text operator so it's great that you pointed it out.